# How can I dodge Marie's attacks?

Tags: skullgirls

Marie, the final boss in Skullgirls, has a lot moves that are either very tricky to dodge or do insane damage (often both). Since she barely moves I can hurt her even by button mashing, but dodging her attacks is the tricky part.

There's certain moves like the big circular shadow on the floor (dash left/right) and the snake of skulls along the floor (jump over) I can dodge, but certain moves like the "assists" coming from behind/in front of you that I can't seem to dodge *or* block. Her explosion (like when turning into her final form) is another tricky one to dodge, attacking in melee it seems I can't get out of the way once I've triggered it.

How can I dodge Marie's attacks, at least the trickiest ones?

Answer (score 2):

Attacks are blocked based on your position relative the other character, not your position relative to the direction the attack is coming from. So even if the attack comes from behind if the opponent is in front you block holding back.

If your character is not blocking even while you're holding the correct direction, than the explanation is that you are not blocking with the correct stance. High attacks need to be blocked while standing, Crouch attacks need to be blocked while crouching. There is also the technique of Jumping backwards and blocking which tends to cover all your bases.

Since I can't say for sure with Marie's attacks I'll also mention that sometimes in fighting games you'll have a small "block buffer" to prevent unfair crossups, so even if the character crosses you up if you were holding the correct direction their fast first crossup hit will get blocked. Very unlikely to apply but there you have it.

I am fairly sure with most characters you have to block some of her attacks and just eat the chip damage.